# Find any string that doesn't start with 'const', or that is preceded by nothing, with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I want to be able to find expressions with `grep` so that (1) they are not preceded by the string `const` (2) but matching those are at the beginning of the line, e.g.:

For point (1), I do `grep -E "[^const]a"`, however this won't work for (2), let me explain:

```
# With the above grep expression:

consta   ---> This won't match because it starts by 'const', ok

xa       |
xxa      |--> All these 3 will match because they don't start by const, ok
xx...xa  |

a        ---> This won't match however it doesn't start with 'const', not ok
```

The last string, an `a` preceded by nothing doesn't match but I want it to do so. **How can I do this?**

Comment: Can you try: `grep -v '^consta' file`

Comment: That would show any line not starting by `consta`

Comment: Use `grep -P '(?<!(?!^)const)a'`

Comment: `[^const]a` doesn't work because it's a negated char set, a big ol' negated and statement. "a single char which is not c and not o and not n and not s and not t followed by a required `a`"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to find all lines that contain the character `a`, but not starting with `const`. You can use this grep with Perl regex:

```
$ cat test
consta
xa
xxa
a
co
something else
2021 a
$ grep -P '^(?!const).*a' test
xa
xxa
a
2021 a
$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of line
- `(?!const)` - negative lookahead for `const`
- `.*a` - literal `a` anywhere on the line